# SplashScreen stuck

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-splashscreen

I'm using the new android Splash Screen with Jetpack Compose. I have a problem with my application logic. It has a presentation screen (onboarding), and on its last page, it has a button to confirm, in this confirmation I save a boolean variable as true in the DataStore.

The logic I did, my Splash screen is stuck and I don't know where I could be going wrong. follow the codes:

**MainActivity**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val viewModel: SplashViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var keepSplashOpened = viewModel.state.keepSplashOpened
        installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition {
            keepSplashOpened
        }
        setContent {
            val window = rememberWindowSizeClass()
            KippTheme(window) {
                val graph = viewModel.state.graphs
                RootNavigationGraph(
                    graph = graph,
                    onDataLoaded = {
                        keepSplashOpened = false
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SplashViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val readOnBoardingUseCase: ReadOnBoardingUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    var state by mutableStateOf(SplashState())

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            readOnBoardingUseCase().collect { completed ->
                state = if (completed) {
                    state.copy(graphs = Graph.HOME, keepSplashOpened = false)
                } else {
                    state.copy(graphs = Graph.WELCOME, keepSplashOpened = false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SplashState**

```
data class SplashState(
    val graphs: String? = null,
    var keepSplashOpened: Boolean = true
)
```

Any personal suggestions?
I'm new to posting here.

the above code is an example and like this is how i tried to do so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
var keepSplashOpened = viewModel.state.keepSplashOpened
installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition {
    keepSplashOpened
}
```

The value of `keepSplashOpened` is captured only one-time and doesn't get updated. To fix it, change the code to

```
installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition {
    viewModel.state.keepSplashOpened
}
```

Comment: It works fine, now another problem has appeared rsrss.
The initial screen of my onboarding appears briefly before going to the Home screen.

It seems that there is some delay in reading the variable saved in the DataStore.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem where the onboarding appears quickly before going home.

In my RootNavigationGraph, it receives a graph, which will be home or welcome, depending on the dataStore result.

And if it is null, I passed the welcome graphic by default, so what did I do:

I created a BlackScreen and a Black graph and pass it instead of the Welcome as the initial destination if the graph is null, it's a palliative but it solves rsrs.
thank you my dear!